# JsonMapper en php, manejo de un JSON

Tags: php, composer

Estoy usando la librería JsonMapper para el mapeo de los JSON, el problema surge cuando encuentro un un nombre con espacio en el json, no es capaz de guardármelo en la variable correcta debido a que tiene un espacio "Tipo Calzado".

```
{
    "data": [
          {
            "client": "Juan",
            "id": "FCE62C2D1",
            "name": "100",
            "uom": "Pair",
            "productCategory": "15",
            "active": true,
            "volume": 0,
            "weight": 0,
            "characteristic": {
                "Color": "NEGRO",
                "Genero": "Hombre",
                "Tipo Calzado": "Deportivas"
            },
            "updated": "2023-09-01 11:41:55.82"
        }
     ]
}
```

Este JSON es un producto el cual confine esta estructura

```
<?php 

require_once ("OrganizationInfo.php");
require_once ("CharacteristicValues.php");

class Product
{
    public ?string $client;
    public ?string $id;
    public ?string $name;
    public ?string $uom;
    public ?string $productCategory;
    public ?bool $active;
    public ?int $volume;
    public ?int $weight;
    public ?Characteristic $characteristic;
    public ?string $updated;

    public function __construct(
        ?string $client = '',
        ?string $id = '',
        ?string $name = '',
        ?string $uom = '',
        ?string $productCategory = '',
        ?bool $active = false,
        ?int $volume = 0,
        ?int $weight = 0,
        ?Characteristic $characteristic = null,
        ?string $updated = ''
    ) {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->uom = $uom;
        $this->productCategory = $productCategory;
        $this->active = $active;
        $this->volume = $volume;
        $this->weight = $weight;
        $this->characteristic = $characteristic !== null ? $characteristic : new Characteristic();
        $this->updated = $updated;
    }
```

Este objeto characteristic:

```
<?php

class Characteristic
{
    public string $Color;
    public string $Genero;
    #[MapFrom("Tipo Calzado")]
    public string $tipoCalzado;

    public function __construct(
        string $Color= '',
        string $Genero = '',
        string $tipoCalzado = ''
    ) {
        $this->Color = $Color;
        $this->Genero = $Genero;
        $this->tipoCalzado = $tipoCalzado;
    }
/// Getters y Setters
```

Clase index

```
use JsonMapper\JsonMapper;
use JsonMapper\JsonMapperFactory;
$mapper = (new JsonMapperFactory())->bestFit();
$jsonData = ApiCall::callAPI("GET", "URL JSON", false);
$product = new Product();
$retP = $mapper->mapArray($data->data, $product);
foreach ($retP as $prod) {
     var_dump($prod);
}
```

Después de mostrarme el var_dump el producto nunca me consigue almacenar el "Tipo Calzado"
dentro de la variable indicada aunque lleve un mapFor.
Entonces no se a que se puede deber esto, si es porque estoy haciendo mal uso de las anotaciones o porque es.

paso lo que me devuelve var_dump

```
object(Product)[163]
  public ?string 'client' => string 'Juan' (length=8)
  public ?string 'id' => string 'FCE62C2D1' (length=32)
  public ?string 'name' => string '100' (length=3)
  public ?string 'uom' => string 'Pair' (length=4)
  public ?string 'productCategory' => string '15' (length=2)
  public ?bool 'active' => boolean true
  public ?int 'volume' => int 0
  public ?int 'weight' => int 0
  public ?Characteristic 'characteristic' => 
    object(Characteristic)[4497]
      public string 'Color' => string 'CUERO' (length=5)
      public string 'Genero' => string 'Hombre' (length=6)
      public string 'tipoCalzado' => *uninitialized*
  public ?string 'updated' => string '2023-09-01 11:41:55.887' (length=23)
```

Entiendo que Color y Genero me lo devuelve porque las variables se llaman igual y están declaradas con mayúscula aunque tendrían que comenzar en minúscula, como podría solucionar esto, he intentando un montón de anotaciones pero ninguna ha funcionado.

Comment: "Tipo Calzado" es una clave; y tiene un espacio en la definicion inicial del json, sacale el espacio para que puedas acceder con: "tipoCalzado"

Comment: Intenta con `$this->{'Tipo Calzado'} = $tipoCalzado;`.

Comment: Sigue dando como resultado, que no se puede inicializar, debido a que no puede acceder a ese nombre por tener un carácter como espacio.  Tiene que tener alguna forma JsonMapper para poder definir nombres de claves sin necesidad de hacer mil y una formas.